# Why did I get +5 rep for voting on this answer?

Tags: support, reputation

I asked [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/35574/why-was-the-nudity-not-censored-in-dragon-ball) on August 4th, and just got a reply today (August 9th). To support the answerer, I upvoted his/her answer. I am not ready to choose it as the best answer, but I will likely select it if no one else answers.

However, upon upvoting his/her answer, I got +5 reputation. Usually you don't get any reputation for upvoting any questions or answers, so why did I get +5?

Comment: Maybe someone voted your question up at the same time? Then it would list the question as the source of the rep, so it could have just been coincidence.

Comment: Does how long it has been between the question being asked and being answered affect the reputation gained?

Comment: No, it's always +5 rep for an upvote on a question, +10 for an upvote on an answer, and +15 for your answer being accepted. Voting on somebody elses stuff doesn't provide you with any rep, if it did I'd be challenging Krazer for the top spot.

Comment: @Matt but you only have 585 votes cast and krazer has 2715

Comment: #Michael McQuade I was just having a bit of a joke :L

Comment: @krazer you have a challenger

Comment: This is a first for me:  Someone asking why they got an addition to reputation........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Your reputation tab](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/26439/the-pickle-tickler?tab=reputation) shows that those +5 reputation points came from an upvote *to your question*. That upvote and yours on the answer just happened at the same time — I double-checked the posts' timelines, and that was indeed the case.